# How to define a global variable on wp-config when working with docker and kubernates

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, jenkins, gitlab

I am newly started to work on docker,jenkins,gitlab etc. I am working on gitlab with a dockerized project. Simply team created a project and now I am making some additions as a intern.

Normally at wordpress we define globals at wp-config like;

```
$BOheader = array("Authorization: SOMEAUTHCODE12381239023",
                  "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
global $BOheader;
```

but on dockerized project manager told me to use it like definition, so i tried code below It surely did not work :)

```
define('BOheader', 'array("Authorization: SOMEAUTHCODE12381239023",
              "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

how can i define $BOHeader variable as global by using secret.yaml file with WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: command. I use definitions like

```
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA:
    define( 'THISPROJECT_DB_HOST_DB_NAME', 'somedbname' );
    define( 'THISPROJECT_DB_HOST_DB_USER', 'somedbuser' );
    define( 'THISPROJECT_DB_HOST_DB_PASSWORD', 'somedbpassword' );
    define( 'THISPROJECT_DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
    define('ENV', 'test');
    define('CURRENCIES', ['en_US' => 'USD', 'tr_TR' => 'INR']);
```

i checked on web and stackoverflow but was not able to reach any document about it

Answer (score 0):

Request and response headers you can set in the same as way as in non dockerised world.

For second query you can use [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and load the values into container.